# Excel - Allow only 1 entry per row cell range

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code working fine to only allow 1 entry to exist within a range in a row (i.e, B3:I3). How would you extend this code to evaluate multiple rows separately, without having to copy, paste and adjust this code over and over for each new row? In other words, how could you ensure only 1 entry is allowed for B3:I3; 1 entry is allowed for B4:I4; 1 entry is allowed for B5:I5; and so on?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim c As Range
    
Set rg = Range("B3:I3")

'is the changed cell in the Range to check
If Not Intersect(Target, rg) Is Nothing Then

'Did you enter something in that cell, or just clear it?
    If Len(Target) > 0 Then
    
'Don't trigger the event endlessly
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each c In rg
        
'make sure to not clear the cell we just changed
            If Intersect(c, Target) Is Nothing Then c.ClearContents
        Next c
    End If
End If

're-enable the event method
Application.EnableEvents = True
        
End Sub
```

The code works fine for a single row, but I would like it to repeat over multiple rows.

Comment: Over multiple rows as in as big as Target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngCols As Range, rngCell As Range
    Dim rngRow As Range, vVal
    Set rngCols = Range("B:I")
    'is the changed cell in the Range to check
    If Not Intersect(Target, rngCols) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Columns.Count = 1 Then
            'Did you enter something in that cell, or just clear it?
            For Each rngCell In Target.Cells
                vVal = rngCell.Value
                If Len(vVal) > 0 Then
                    'Don't trigger the event endlessly
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    Set rngRow = Intersect(rngCols, rngCell.EntireRow)
                    'make sure to not clear the cell we just changed
                    rngRow.ClearContents
                    rngCell.Value = vVal
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If
    're-enable the event method
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: A lot more eloquent than what I was fiddling around with. Going from the target each cell's intersect with the B:I is far easier than reverse, gj :)

Answer (score 0):

You may be after this (not so sure about your goal...)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim watchedRng As Range
        Set watchedRng = Range("B3:I5") ' <-- set the range you want to ensure each row of which has only 1 value

        Dim sensibleRng As Range
            Set sensibleRng = Intersect(Target, watchedRng)

                If Not sensibleRng Is Nothing Then

                    Set sensibleRng = Intersect(sensibleRng.EntireRow, watchedRng)
                    Dim myRow As Range
                        For Each myRow In sensibleRng.Rows

                            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myRow) > 1 Then

                                    With Intersect(Target, myRow)
                                    
                                        Dim nValues As Long
                                            nValues = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells)
                                            If nValues > 1 Then
                                                MsgBox "I don't know which of the new " & nValues & " values I have to preserve in row " & .row
                                            Else
                                            
                                                Dim val As Variant
                                                    val = .Value
                                                    
                                                    On Error GoTo SafeExit ' be sure you will be able to set Application.EnableEvents back True
                                                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                                                        myRow.ClearContents
                                                        Intersect(myRow, Target).Value = val
                                            
                                            End If
                                        
                                    End With                                        
                                        
                            End If

                        Next
        End If

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this also works, but I could only choose 1 answer.

Comment: you are welcome
but my solution differs from the other one by covering all possible limit cases
you may simply have not met them (and maybe you'll not meet them forever...)